# Which java data structures have a deterministic order of iteration?

Tags: java, collections

In an interview, I was asked the following question:

> Your application requires to store objects such that the order of
>   entries returned  while iterating  through the structure is
>   deterministic. In other words, if you  iterate over  the same
>   structure twice,  the order of elements returned  in both  iterations
>   will be the same. Which of the following classes would  you  use?

Assume that structure is not mutated. (Check ANY that apply)

```
HashMap 
LinkedHashSet   
HashTable   
LinkedHashMap
TreeSet 
TreeMap
```

I suggested using a LinkedHashSet. Was this the correct answer? Why or why not?

Comment: Why did you choose a LinkedHashMap? Can you explain your reasoning and why your choice was better/worse than other choices?

Comment: @DavidJones since the order need to be maintained was in my mind please advise is it correct approach Thanks in advance

Comment: i thnk solution is there http://www.coderanch.com/t/248485/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/collection

Comment: As long as the structure is not mutated, all of them would result in the same iteration order (now if you need to preserve insertion order, that's a different question).

Comment: The order will also be deterministic for `TreeSet`, `TreeMap` and `LinkedHashSet`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think they may've been trying to trick the OP…? Either way, I think this is a bad interview question. It can be googled and solved in a matter of minutes.

Comment: A better question would be "which of these provide a sensible iteration order". LinkedHashX sort by insertion order, TreeX sort by value.

Answer (score 5):

A **determenistic** order just means that it's constantly reproducible - the same input will always provide the same iteration order. In this case, the answer is "all of the above". Although most `Set`'s and `Map`'s ordering can't be trusted, it is still determenistic, and will remain the same until the underlying implementation is changed (e.g., if you change or upgrade JVMs).

A **predictable** order is something more, though - it means that the collection guarantees the order items are returned when iterating the collection. Both "linked" types you mentioned above do that - the order that items were inserted to the collection is the order they will be returned when iterating over it. The "tree" types also guarantee a deterministic order of iteration - a sorted one.

Comment: The Tree collections do that as well - they sort by the key.

Comment: TreeXXX are also "predictable".  Technically, HashMap is also predictable, just not by a sane human.

Comment: @user949300 I've seen (badly coded) applications that implicitly assume the order of iteration of a `HashMap` break when they were upgraded from Java 1.4 to Java 5 - it's deterministic within the same JDK, but by all means not predictable.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @Elliot Frisch, they are all "deterministic" and will iterate in the same order if nothing has changed.  That said, to paraphrase Animal House, some collections are more deterministic than others.  :-)

**Hash...** collections have a **deterministic** iteration order which the JVM can "predict", but is very challenging for a human to predict and not worth the effort.  In practice, they are **not "predictable"**.  As @Mureinik points out, the order is officially "unspecified" and subject to change of you change JVMs.  The [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) describe this as "generally chaotic ordering" and all sane programmers would agree.

**Linked...** collections have "predictable iteration order" in that they iterate in the order elements were inserted, with the important caveat that if you insert the same element twice it retains the *original* order.  i.e.

```
add("Tom");
add("Fred");
add("Tom");
```

would iterate "Tom", "Fred", **not** "Fred", "Tom"

This is clearly "**more predictable**" than Hash..., but still a bit challenging if elements get inserted multiple times and ordering is crucial.  For stuff like properties files, XML, or JSON, Linked... collections are generally a good choice as they maintain the original order for nicer human viewing and comparison.

**Tree...** collections iterate the "**most predictably**", using the ordering provided by a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) at construction time, or else the "natural ordering" if the elements are [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).  Assuming you have a predicable comparison method, they are completely predictable.  In the Tom/Fred example, it would always iterate as "Fred", "Tom", unless your Comparator is unusual.

Comment: "some collections are more deterministic than others" - I think I know what you're trying to say, but would you mind clarifying for the reader?

Comment: *That said, to paraphrase Animal House, some collections are more deterministic than others* George Orwell wrote [Animal Farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Farm) (where some animals are more equal than others). [Animal House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_House) is a film from National Lampoon. [Food fight!](https://youtu.be/hLdO2V1CTF0)

Comment: Oops, I did mean Animal Farm of course.  Surprised nobody caught the mistake earlier.

Answer (score 0):

When answering this type of questions, I would highly suggest doing so according to the [Java API Specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/api-141528.html) and not based on your assumptions of the implementations. So for example, even though you could argue that all the of those collections would have a deterministic iteration order provided that they are not mutated between repeated iterations, because you think it would not make sense to implement it that way, the only real answer—according to the options you listed—strictly adhering to the Java API Specification would be **all except HashMap and HashTable**.

The reason for answering this is that of all of them, according to the Java API Specification, the only classes that give no guarantee on the iteration order are those two I mentioned (HashMap and HashTable). So in general, when you program in Java, you should never assume an specific implementation of the API and or the JVM or anything that is based on an Specification unless that Specification.

So, as an example, what could be a problem of assuming a particular implementation for the HashSet collection? The thing is that the JDK that might be used to run your program (which is not necessarily the same you use for developing) could implement the HashTable with certain optimizations as long as it doesn't violate the Java API Specification, and such optimization could be such that if for example, a HashTable is not used for 10 minutes, then it could call the rehash function automatically in order to reorganized and optimize the access to its entries. And this is a possible scenario, because as noted here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html "*The exact details as to when and whether the rehash method is invoked are implementation-dependent*".